# Remove country code from phone number?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Below is the code I am currently using to format phone numbers for databasing. However iOS is putting a +1 or 1 (country code) before it in autofills. How can I remove the 1 before the phone number?

So...

+12223334444 should be 2223334444

12223334444 should be 2223334444

```
preg_replace('/\D/', '', ($phone));
```

Comment: try this `/^\+?1/`

Comment: So you only get US phone numbers? Never anything else?

Comment: If you just need the last 10 characters, you can use `substr($phone, -10)` but it is hard to image that this would get you a reliable database of phone numbers...

Comment: How do I add /^\+?1/ to /\D/

Comment: @Tony you don't need to add my formula to yours - completely replace your regex with mine, and it will work.

Comment: You can try this library https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the following regex substitution:

if your format is : `+12223334444`

```
$country_code = '+1';
$phone_no = '+12223334444';

echo preg_replace('/^\+?1|\|1|\D/', '', ($phone_no));
```

Output will : `2223334444`

if your format is : `12223334444`

```
$country_code = '1';
$phone_no = '2223334444';

echo preg_replace('/^\+?1|\|1|\D/', '', ($phone_no));
```

Output will : `2223334444`

Comment: That breaks phone numbers formatted like this +1999-999-9999

Comment: Yeah, that removes the +1 from the begging, but it doesn't remove just 1 and it doesn't remove all the other formatting that /\D/ does.

Comment: @Tony Accept my answer :) If this answer is solved your problem

Comment: and it doesn't remove all the other formatting that /\D/ does., how do I add that in?

Comment: Hypens, periods, dashes, and middle dots need to be handled as well.

Comment: can you put some example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177704/discussion-between-tony-and-siddharth-ramani).

Answer (score 10):

This may be overkill, but here we go:

```
\+(?:998|996|995|994|993|992|977|976|975|974|973|972|971|970|968|967|966|965|964|963|962|961|960|886|880|856|855|853|852|850|692|691|690|689|688|687|686|685|683|682|681|680|679|678|677|676|675|674|673|672|670|599|598|597|595|593|592|591|590|509|508|507|506|505|504|503|502|501|500|423|421|420|389|387|386|385|383|382|381|380|379|378|377|376|375|374|373|372|371|370|359|358|357|356|355|354|353|352|351|350|299|298|297|291|290|269|268|267|266|265|264|263|262|261|260|258|257|256|255|254|253|252|251|250|249|248|246|245|244|243|242|241|240|239|238|237|236|235|234|233|232|231|230|229|228|227|226|225|224|223|222|221|220|218|216|213|212|211|98|95|94|93|92|91|90|86|84|82|81|66|65|64|63|62|61|60|58|57|56|55|54|53|52|51|49|48|47|46|45|44\D?1624|44\D?1534|44\D?1481|44|43|41|40|39|36|34|33|32|31|30|27|20|7|1\D?939|1\D?876|1\D?869|1\D?868|1\D?849|1\D?829|1\D?809|1\D?787|1\D?784|1\D?767|1\D?758|1\D?721|1\D?684|1\D?671|1\D?670|1\D?664|1\D?649|1\D?473|1\D?441|1\D?345|1\D?340|1\D?284|1\D?268|1\D?264|1\D?246|1\D?242|1)\D?
```

[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/AsuVYw)

In order to match any prefix and since some countries could share partially same prefix (for example 1 and 1-721), you add all positibilities to the regex in descending order and size.

The regex is based on [this list](https://countrycode.org/).

Comment: The trouble with this is that an international prefix may need to be replaced with an empty string in some countries, or with another prefix (like `"0"` in the UK) in some countries.

Comment: @Flimm, Do you mean using `00` instead of `+`?

Comment: No. I mean +44123456789 in the UK is dialled 0123456789, not 123456789.

Comment: Well, you may have an associative hash with the prefixes and their trunk prefixes. And then add the trunk prefix accordingly. Here is a list with the countries and trunk prefixes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_prefix

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (substr($request->mobile_num, 0, 2) == "98")
        $mobile_num = str_replace('98', '0', $request->mobile_num);
 elseif (substr($request->mobile_num, 0, 3) == "+98")
        $mobile_num = str_replace('+98', '0', $request->mobile_num);
 else
     $mobile_num = $request->mobile_num;
```

Answer (score 1):

It cleans phone number & strips (, ), -, +
returns just last 10 digit numeric phone number

Examples:

```
1234567890 => +11234567890
1234567890 => :+112:34567890
1234567890 => Phone :+1-123-456-7890
1234567890 => Phone :+1-(123)-(456)-(7890)
1234567890 => +1-(123)-(456)-(7890)
1234567890 => +1-123-456-7890

Sample test code:
```

```
$dirty_phone = ["+11234567890", ":+112:34567890", "Phone :+1-123-456-7890",  "Home :(+1)-(123)-(456)-(7890)", "+1-(123)-(456)-(7890)", "+1-123-456-7890"];

foreach ($dirty_phone as $key => $phone_no) {
    $cleaned_phone = clean_phone_number($phone_no);
    echo "{$cleaned_phone} => {$phone_no}<br>";
}

function clean_phone_number($phone_no){
    return substr( preg_replace('/^\+?1|\|1|\D/', '', $phone_no), -10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on credit facility USSD. The USSD captures the phone number with the country code and I wanted to send sms notification via another bulk sms API that only requires mobile number without country code. I used the below code and it works fine.

```
<?php

$country_code = '+254';
$phone_no = '+254712450866';

echo preg_replace('/^\+?254|\|1|\D/', '0', ($phone_no));

?>
```

USSD captures +254712450866
the above code formats to 0712450866

For me it works.